# Filtering the data based on values in the columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have been working on some data lately. During the filtering process, I found some columns have some issue. I want to only keep those rows which have ')' present at the last in the Branch columns.

I have tried several options but the i want to find fastest way to go around it.

[image: This is a part of the data on which i have been working on.]

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data as text (ideally as a code fragment that we could use to rebuild the sample). We cannot copy data from a screenshot.

Comment: thank you for pointing out!. I will work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide your data as text, I have created an example dataframe:

Input:

```
d = {'college_name': ['College {}'.format(i+1) for i in range(8)], 'branch': ['Civil Enigineering '+ '(4 Years)'*(i%2) for i in range(8)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['college_name','branch'])
df
```

Output:

```
    college_name    branch
0   College 1   Civil Enigineering
1   College 2   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
2   College 3   Civil Enigineering
3   College 4   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
4   College 5   Civil Enigineering
5   College 6   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
6   College 7   Civil Enigineering
7   College 8   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
```

Pandas series have built in string processing methods. You can use str.endswith(')') to filter your data. Notice that `df['branch'].str.endswith(')')` will return a boolean mask.

Input:

```
df[df['branch'].str.endswith(')')]
```

Output:

```
    college_name    branch
1   College 2   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
3   College 4   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
5   College 6   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
7   College 8   Civil Enigineering (4 Years)
```

Comment: Please consider marking this problem with the checkmark to the left of the question if you think it is the best answer. Thanks!